# $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] not working

Tags: javascript, php

I have the current set up of...
a javascript file containing

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: 'GET',
    url: './memberfunctions/getRef.php',
    data: {},
    beforeSend:function(){
    },
    success:function(data){
        // successful request; do something with the data
        console.log(data);
    },
    error:function(){
        // failed request; give feedback to user
        alert("idk what happened");
    }
});
});
```

getRef.php is

```
<?php

$httpReferer = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : null;

echo $httpReferer;

?>
```

If i go to pastebin, type in and click mysite.com, i go to mysite.com and the console says mysite.com. Obviously I want the console to say pastebin.com/######

I know HTTP_REFERER is insecure, vulnerable, poor, unreliable. It serves a tiny non-vital purpose.

Comment: Did you check if the browser is sending a "referrer" header in the HTTP Request? You can do this with the developer tools.

Comment: you need to pass `document.referrer` in your ajax request and look at that instead of `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your AJAX request, the referrer is not pastebin.com. Your parent page would have had the referrer set to pastebin.

You can try something like this as inline script:

`<script>
var ref = "<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?>";
</script>`

OR below which need not be inline

`<script>
var ref = document.referrer;
</script>`

Unless am missing something in the intent of the AJAX call.

Comment: When mixing php&js you need to `echo` $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

Comment: Thanks @Alon, am not very used to PHP. Corrected as per your comment.

Comment: Perfect! I suspected this was the case.